# Does either Coddington & Levinson's and Hirsch & Smale's differential equations book cover Floquet Theory?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, book-recommendation

I wish to review some material for my qualifying exam on ODEs/PDEs, and I've started to read both Coddington & Levinson's *Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations* and Hirsh & Smale's *Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and Linear Algebra* (1st edition, not the edition with Devaney).  I love the writing style of both books and have my heart set on reading one of them.

However, I need a book which covers Floquet Theory as that is one of the topics covered in the qual.  I looked in the index of both books, but there wasn't an entry on Floquet's Theorem.  I know not all books have a thorough index, so I'm hoping this was just an oversight in these books, or they just don't specifically use the term Floquet Theory while covering the topic.

Can anyone who's very familiar with either of these two books tell me if they cover Floquet Theory? Thanks in advance to everyone who can offer me some insight into my question!

Comment: One of Coddington and Levinson's books definitely cover Floquet theory; I think the one on linear ode.

Comment: You might also check out J.K. Hale's *Ordinary Differential Equations* (I think I got the title right but it shouldn't be hard to find in any event.)  It too is well-written and covers Floquet theory.

Comment: @RobertLewis I did look at Hale's book, but his Chapter 0: Mathematical Preliminaries scared me off a little.  Maybe after I read Hirsh/Smale or Coddington/Levinson.

Comment: Robert is right I see Floquet theorem on page 119 Hale's book. But I don't find Floquet in Coddington's book Op mentioned

Comment: The first  chapter of Hale, is as I recall pretty general and abstract, but I think if you just go straight to the chapters on Linear and Periodic systems you should be able to jump in.

Comment: Hale is available online:  https://epdf.pub/ordinary-differential-equations5d3535e7fb0f102b65b0699ff7a0bcd433530.html